# How to run queries against a set of parameters in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am looking for a way to run a parameterized query against a number of parameters in parallel in Google BigQuery, is this possible?

For example I am looking for something that can run something like the below query:

```
WITH generic_query AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM start_date) as date
         , COUNT(0) as total
      FROM multi_tennant_visit_table
     WHERE start_date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
       AND company_id = @companyId
)
```

Against a fixed `@startDate` and `@endDate` but some sort of array of `@companyId` values and return the data as a structured response in the following (`JSON`) format:

```
[
  {
    "company_id": "1",
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "2019-01-01",
        "total": "1431"
      },
      {
        "date": "2019-01-02",
        "total": "1876"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "company_id": "2",
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "2019-01-01",
        "total": "1431"
      },
      {
        "date": "2019-01-02",
        "total": "1876"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

However this is a very oversimplified as `company_id` is hierarchical, in that a visit from the table may be associated with a company and it's parent company, and that companies parent companies etc, which is all handled in a level structure not shown here.

Additionally I would like to run around 20 queries in this manner, some are simple and could be re-written to just group by the `company_id` and `ARRAY_AGG()` and `STRUCT()` used to end up with the response format I'm looking for, but some simply cannot as they use `@companyId` in a couple of nested sub-queries, and I need to maintain explain-ability to stakeholders, ie, this runs the query we have at all scopes, here are the results.

Is there a way to do this in bigquery (as one query ideally) as I am looking at 1000s of `@company_id` values and a couple GB/day database, so don't want costs to spiral.

Many thanks, if there are any further clarifications needed, feel free to ask

Update:

I have tried converting the subquery into a function which accepts `company` as a variable, but am receiving the following error:

> Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Composer (Apache Airflow) is used to implement such usecases. You can take a look at `airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator` . An example of using this operator is as below:-

```
from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_operator
    # Query recent StackOverflow questions.
    bq_recent_questions_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='bq_recent_questions_query',
        bql="""
        SELECT owner_display_name, title, view_count
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
        WHERE creation_date < CAST('{max_date}' AS TIMESTAMP)
            AND creation_date >= CAST('{min_date}' AS TIMESTAMP)
        ORDER BY view_count DESC
        LIMIT 100
        """.format(max_date=max_query_date, min_date=min_query_date),
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        destination_dataset_table=bq_recent_questions_table_id)
```

The entire code sample can be found here [1]

1 - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/f89ac82ea18a08398cc54762c638c686c6f938fa/composer/workflows/bq_notify.py

Answer (score 0):

Even though the Composer approach mentioned earlier it's one option, you have to consider if it's cost effective, Composer uses a lot of resources which could be expensive.

You can try using a function to extract the parameters of your [nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890969/how-to-navigate-in-nested-json) file and then using [parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery_query_params_named-cli) to provide those parameters for your query.

Comment: This is more the sort of thing I'm thinking about, and why I was trying to run as a function, there are 10s of thousands of scopes and the costs will spiral (and take exponentially longer). I think the way I'm going to try and approach this is to create a nested result for each scope, then pass the data through as a parameter to the UDF.