# How do I save JSON response text as a variable

Tags: json, variables

I'm very new to this, and I'm looking to make a very simple API to automatically close a web payment register. To do this, I need to save the totals for each payment type as variables directly from the GET response text.

```
 "data": {
        "register_open_time": "2020-04-23T00:52:20+00:00",

"payments": [
            {
                "payment_type_name": "Web DPS",
                "total": "8.00",
                "payment_type_id": "02dcd191-aea1-11e6-f485-3739a66c2e0a"
            },
            {
                "payment_type_name": "Direct Credit",
                "total": "0.00",
                "payment_type_id": "02dcd191-aea1-11e6-f485-373951b76d5e"
            },
            {
                "payment_type_name": "Cash",
                "total": "0.00",
                "payment_type_id": "0a422413-2fb9-11e6-ff63-13162b07766b"
            },
            {
                "payment_type_name": "EFTPOS",
                "total": "0.00",
                "payment_type_id": "e3a8e4d0-c41d-43ec-b309-efdbb2f89b5f"
            },
            {
                "payment_type_name": "Amex",
                "total": "0.00",
                "payment_type_id": "02dcd191-aea1-11e6-f485-38c78a22e1ac"
            },
            {
                "payment_type_name": "EFTPOS Corrections",
                "total": "0.00",
                "payment_type_id": "02dcd191-aea1-11e6-f485-3d73dbc1b391"
            },
            {
                "payment_type_name": "Cheque",
                "total": "0.00",
                "payment_type_id": "0a422413-2fa1-11e6-ff63-132003198e62"
            },
            {
                "payment_type_name": "Cash rounding",
                "total": "0.00",
                "payment_type_id": "02dcd191-aea1-11e6-f485-48a335417b10"
            },
            {
                "payment_type_name": "Gift Card",
                "total": "0.00",
                "payment_type_id": "0a422413-2fa1-11e6-ff63-133c6dab5ef9"
            }
```

I have the variables set up and ready to go, but I've just not quite got a handle on how to extract the values.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You could serialize it. The way of doing so depends on every programming language though

Comment: I'm working in Javascript for this.

Comment: Take a look at this post. Might help. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6890969/9915307